# Order of books in A Song of Ice and Fire

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, suggested-order

There are numerous ways to read *A Song of Ice and Fire* I have done the research. I would like to read the 4th and 5th books simultaneously but I read that you can read *A Knight of Seven Kingdoms* before *A Dance With Dragons*. Would it be OK to read *A Knight of Seven Kingdoms* before *A Feast For Crows* and then read book 4 and 5 simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, they're not directly correlated. However reading 4&5 simultaneously is futile, just read 4 then 5.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the books in their order of publication, it would then  acknowledge the intent of GRRM and partake of the commonality of experience of his multitudinous readers. First read of course; mix it up later if achieving chaos or some other goal is sought.